# Define Python version inside project

Tags: python

Many times I work on other developers' projects. I need to detect the Python version they used and sometimes it is hard to find.

I want to define which interpreter version I am using inside my project so that future developers will know which one to use.

Is there any standard (acceptable) way to do it, is it `README.md`?

Comment: Couldn't you just specify the version in a docstring at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I could specify it in many places. This is why I am asking this question. I am looking for the acceptable way to do it

Comment: Why *not* in the README?

Comment: I don`t care where to place it. If README is the most acceptable place so this is the answer for my question

Comment: But you said *except* the README.

Comment: So may be the use of the work `except` was not in place... I will edit my question

Comment: It's usually placed in `tox.ini`, `.travis.yml` or any other CI-intentioned file. Having it in README is the most readable for human beings :)

Comment: Yeah, the `README` is the usual place.  [Example](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework#requirements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best option I found and using it is inside the `README.md` file:

```
# Requirements

* Python (2.7.13)
```

Answer (score 5):

[pyenv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get/1195153#1195153) has the [`.python-version` file](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/806b30d6ce5b263a765648fbcdd68266833b7289#choosing-the-python-version) which can be created with:

```
pyenv local 3.8.0
```

The file simply contains the string `3.8.0`. Users can then enable that specific python version with:

```
pyenv local
```

In [Python Poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry) you can [add to your `pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/tree/68d6939f2e9cac1178fc5ffbcc3bac7a9db43fce#introduction):

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~2.7 || ^3.2"  # Compatible python versions must be declared here
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining [Requires-Python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#core-metadata-requires-python) in a *pyproject.yaml* file should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if there is a standard convention, but for development repositories I have created I add a `__python_version__` special attribute along with the `__author__` and other attributes at the top. This way it is simple and quick to call when you import the package (no searching strings or readmes), and consistent.

```
import x as y
y.__python_version__
```